# appium css selector is not supported for this session

Tags: testing, appium

While using appium through desktop app, with interface, setting all ports manually it works perfectly, but when I try to launch using cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4279 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone
```

my code is:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Snapchat"); 
cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.snapchat.android"); 
cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.snapchat.android.app.main.activity.LoginAndSignupActivity");
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4279/wd/hub"), cap);

Thread.Sleep(5000);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.snapchat.android:id/login_and_signup_page_fragment_login_button")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

It fails with 'css selector' is not supported for this session
error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing 
`from selenium import webdriver`

with this one:
`from appium import webdriver`

Answer (score 0):

Usually for native app, there is no CSS selector. Only for hybrid app, there will be . So people use class name,Id,name or xpath to identify elements Or If you have webview in you application like clicking help page redirects to website link, then you can use css selector

Comment: This is a fairly unclear answer that could be improved by spending a few more words of explanation.

Comment: Can you please let me know what's explanation needed to make answer really fair? Usually for native app, there is no CSS selector. Only for hybrid app, there will be . So people use class name,Id,name or xpath to identify elements Or If you have webview in you application  like clicking help page redirects to website link, then you can use css selector.

Comment: I'd say, the extra words you used in the comment would do the job! It's just, that most of the time some extra text really helps to get the point across and to provide some more info.